# Error ConverterNotFoundException Springboot Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, api, spring-data-jpa

I am working on a project using Springboot to create API to call all provinces in the list. So first i create an entity class

```
package example.parameter.entity;


import lombok.Data;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import java.util.List;

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "provinces",indexes = {
        @Index(name = "PROVINCES_INDX_0", columnList = "name")
})
public class Province extends BaseEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "provinces_generator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "provinces_generator", sequenceName = "provinces_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "is_deleted")
    private Boolean isDeleted;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "province", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Regency> regencies;

    @NotBlank
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
}
```

and then I created this responseDTO

```
package example.parameter.api.response;

import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class ProvinceResponseDTO {

    private String id;
    private String name;

}
```

after that I create the repository

```
package example.parameter.repository;

import example.parameter.api.response.ProvinceResponseDTO;
import example.parameter.entity.Province;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;

import java.util.List;

public interface ProvinceRepository extends JpaRepository<Province,Long> {

    
    public List<ProvinceResponseDTO> findAllByIsDeleted(Boolean isDeleted);


}
```

when I am trying to hit the API I am getting this error on data layer.

```
org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [example.parameter.entity.Province] to type [example.api.response.ProvinceResponseDTO]
```

I don't know thy this is happening, any solution to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Part:1

JpaRepository Query creation from method name should have the default return type of the entity object. In your case, your repository is for the Province entity. So, it should be like

```java
public interface ProvinceRepository extends JpaRepository<Province, Long> {

    public List<Province> findAllByIsDeleted(Boolean isDeleted);

}
```

Reference:-
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html

Part: 2

If you need to return a custom object from the query creation from a method name, then you can use dynamic projections like below:-

```java
public interface ProvinceRepository extends JpaRepository<Province, Long> {

    public <T> List<T> findAllByIsDeleted(Boolean isDeleted, Class<T> dynamicClassType);

}
```

while calling this method you define like

```java
provinceRepository.findAllByIsDeleted(true, ProvinceResponseDTO.class)
```

Reference:- https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections.dtos

Comment: Thanks for your advice, but in this case, I just want to show id and name of the Province instead show all the properties in the entity

Comment: It would be better if you put a reference link along with the explanation of JpaRepository in your answer. [JpaRepository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html)

Comment: @myeongkilkim, thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @Waterloow1 I have updated the answer for your use case